# Type 'Observable<any[] | Observable<any[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular7, angular-ngselect

I'm using **ng-select v2** and **angular 7**.

I'm getting an error at the return statement below

```
getHospital(term: string = null): Observable<Hospitals[]> {
    let items = this.getHospitals1();
    if (term) {
      items = items.pipe(
        filter((x,i) => x[i].name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1)
      )
    }
    return of(items).pipe(delay(500));
  }
```

3 errors which says:

> - Type 'Observable>' is not    assignable to type 'Observable'.
> - Type 'Hospitals[] | Observable' is not assignable to type 'Hospitals[]'.
> - Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Hospitals[]'.

here's my **getHospitals1** function

```
getHospitals1() : Observable<Hospitals[]>{
    return this.http.get<Hospitals[]>('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/monsterbrain/FakeJsonServer/hospitals')
   }

export interface Hospitals {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  address: string;
}
```

What should be changed to fix this ?

Comment: replace `return of(items).pipe(delay(500));` with `return items.pipe(delay(500))` : items are already observable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you are facing is with the line `return of(items).pipe(delay(500));` It is turning your `Observable<any[]>` into an `Observable<Observable<any[]>` when using the `of` function. Simply pipe the current Observable to the delay and you will be good to go.

```js
return items.pipe(delay(500));
```